# Фокус на блок при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Смотрите, допустим, я нажимаю на кнопку и ниже проявляется блок, к примеру вне видения пользователя. Ниже того что он видит. Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку появлялся блок и пользователя фокусировало на блок ниже. То есть есть страница опускалась плавно до блока. А не оставалась на текущем месте. Желательно чистый css/html/js без чего либо. Сделайте примерный код в комментариях пожалуйста. Особой стилизации не нужно. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Что Вы уже сделали (кроме задавания этого вопроса), чтобы решить данную задачу?

Comment: кнопку и блок который появляется по нажатию))

Comment: "Но Вы нам их не покажете?" Почтальон Печкин

Comment: Я могу сейчас написать дефолтный фаст код под этот вопрос, нужно?

Comment: Это целиком и полностью на Ваше усмотрение.

Comment: Если помочь можете - я сделаю. Я это и спрашиваю

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105052/discussion-between-w3cwhy-and-igor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, вам нужно это?:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.block').show();
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.block').offset().top + "px"
  }, {
    duration: 1E3
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.block {
  margin: 200px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Кнопка</button>
<div class="block">Скрытый блок</div>
```